# Is there a way to write a SQL query that counts the orders of a season (e.g. winter) of every season across a given year span (2000 - 2010)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

Clearly you can do the regular query such as-

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT (ordernum))
FROM orders
WHERE DATES BETWEEN '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27' AS 'Winter Season'
GROUP BY ordernum
```

and maybe a CASE statement to name your seasons. But ideally, what I'd like is the below:

[image]

The logic:

- Spring is March - June
- Summer is June to September
- Fall September- December
- Winter is December - March

Comment: What is the logic for your seasons?

Comment: Basically: Spring is March - June | Summer is June to September |Fall September- December | Winter is December - March

Comment: Sounds like a good column to add to a [date table](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/).

Comment: Like add it in addition to the Order table?

Comment: You will struggle if you cannot define your boundaries explicitly. For example, June cannot be both in Spring and in Summer. You might be able to use the standard QUARTER part of a date to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `case` expression *as the `group by` key.  I suspect something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(date),
       (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'WINTER'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 'SPRING'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 'SUMMER'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 'AUTUMN'
        END) as season, COUNT(*)
FROM orders
GROUP BY  YEAR(date),
          (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'WINTER'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 'SPRING'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 'SUMMER'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 'AUTUMN'
           END);
```

EDIT:

If you want the average across years, use arithmetic:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'WINTER'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 'SPRING'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 'SUMMER'
             WHEN MONTH(date) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 'AUTUMN'
        END) as season,
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(date))
FROM orders
GROUP BY  (CASE WHEN MONTH(date) IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 'WINTER'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (4, 5, 6) THEN 'SPRING'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (7, 8, 9) THEN 'SUMMER'
                WHEN MONTH(date) IN (10, 11, 12) THEN 'AUTUMN'
           END);
```

Comment: Can i do an Average(Count(*)) after 'as season'?

Comment: @opaul, sure, you can do AVG, MAX, MIN functions there

Comment: mb you mean ... WHEN MONTH(date) IN (**12, 1, 2**) THEN 'WINTER'...?

Comment: @АлександрГрабовский, pretty much . I dont have high reputation, but thank you

Comment: But this doesnt work because, you
cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: @opaul, have you studied the chapter on sub-queries yet? Hint: This is the sub-query you need to implement the solution to the problem on your assignment.

Comment: @opaul wrap this entire query inside a sub query and group by season and calculate `avg(c)` (where c is an alias for count(*)).